# Filtering wp_title() in WordPress

Tags: wp-title

I am using this in header file of my site.

```
<title><?php wp_title( '|', true, 'right' ); ?></title>
```

But it is displays '|' at the end of title on all the pages of site like this

```
<title>Our Company - SEO Company 1SEOIN |</title>
```

I want to remove this '|'. How can I do this?

Comment: Being an SEO company you should check the first result in Google http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_title

Comment: @Wyck it does not solve my problem

Comment: Inanimate web pages usually don't solve problems on their own, problems like this require reading and then typing on your part.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is type

```
wp_title('');
```

instead

```
wp_title( '|', true, 'right' );
```